When does baseline subtraction increase statistical power?
Suppose you have two groups of subjects (placebo and drug, say), with each subject measured both pre-treatment and post-treatment. I am aware that this sort of design can be analyzed multiple ways, e.g. t-test on pre-post difference (i.e. delta) scores, hybrid two-way ANOVA, ANCOVA...
Question: When does the baseline subtraction (delta score) approach increase statistical power, versus just comparing the post-treatment scores? It must depend on how well the scores correlate, i.e. pre-treatment vs. post-treatment, and I think I read somewhere that this Pearson correlation coefficient has to be at least 0.5. Is this the case, or does it depend?

This paper shows that: If the required sample size for a t-test on post-scores requires $n$ subjects, an ANCOVA requires $(1 - \rho^2)n$ subjects whereas a t-test on the change-scores requires $(2 - 2\rho)n$ subjects. So the change score analysis requires more subjects when $\rho<0.5$ and fewer if $\rho >0.5$.

Power will be increased whenever the correlation is not 0.  It will be increased more, other things being equal, if it is farther from 0.

I think there is something that happens at a correlation of 0.5 - more here.
